# Texhash has no permission for home directory

Tags: installing, texlive

I have recently updated TexLive through `tlmgr`. After that I got several errors when running LaTeX saying that some `.sty` file was not found. Those files exist, and when I run `texhash` I recive:

> ```
> texhash: Updating /home/markl/texlive/2013/texmf-config/ls-R... 
> texhash: /home/markl/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R: no write permission, skipping...
> texhash: Updating /home/markl/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/ls-R... 
> texhash: Updating /home/markl/texlive/2013/texmf-var/ls-R... 
> texhash: Done.
> ```

Any idea?

Comment: Try `sudo texhash`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems you have a TeX Live installed in your home. Check the owner of `/home/markl/texlive` and of directories below it. It should be you and not root or some other user.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I've checked the file permission and found that `/home/markl/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R` was not owned by me (not sure the reason). After changing the owner now texhash can be run properly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be in wrong ownership of directories or files.

If TeX Live is installed in the home directory, it should be managed without ever using `sudo` and usually `tlmgr` does the right thing. But it can happen that ownerships or permissions get screwed. Check for them.

```
ls -dl /home/markl/texlive
ls -dl /home/markl/texlive/2013
ls -dl /home/markl/texlive/2013/texmf-dist
ls -l /home/markl/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R
```

might give the clue.